# Am I properly negating the definition of this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

The statement:

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows: $x\in A$ if and only if there exists $c>0$ so that
$$ |x-j2^{-k}|\geq c2^{-k} $$
holds for all $j\in \mathbb{Z}$ and integers $k\geq 0$.

---

The negation of the above statement:

$x\in A^{c}$ if and only if for all $c>0$, we have that
$$ |x-j2^{-k}|<c2^{-k} $$
holds for all $j\in \mathbb{Z}$ and integers $k\geq 0$.

Comment: 'For all' becomes 'there exists' and 'there exists' becomes 'for all'; so you should say for some $j\in \mathbb Z$ and some integer $k \geq 0$.